# why not change intem in my config file? (Codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've created a config file with the next code:

```
$config['site_name'] = 'Cotizador';
$config['impost_iva'] = '16';
$config['phone_number'] = '5523646564';
$config['owner_name'] = 'Mario Alberto';
$config['main_email'] = 'info@oiramweb.com';
```

And I'm trying change its values through the next code

```
class Sends extends CI_Controller{

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->config('general_settings');
        $this->load->model('inserts');
    }

    public function updateConfig(){
        $company = $this->input->post('name_company');
        $iva = $this->input->post('impost');
        $number = $this->input->post('phone');
        $owner = $this->input->post('owner');
        $email = $this->input->post('email');

        $this->config->set_item('impost_iva', 10);


        echo 'Las modificacions fueron ralizadas con éxito';

        echo $this->config->item('impost_iva');

    }
}
```

But this method don't do any change. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

While you can dynamically set/change existing config items its important to know that the dynamic setting is not written to the config file. This means the set value will only be usable for the current CodeIgniter instance.

CodeIgniter does not provide any methods designed to write to config files.